# Transform polygons using matrices

Tags: numpy, matrix, vector

What is the better way to transform polygons using matrices?

```
mat = np.array([[-0.75, 0],[0,-0.75]])
a = np.array([0, 4])
b = np.array([-4, 8])
c = np.array([-8, 0])
d = np.array([-8, -4])
e = np.array([-4, -4])

np.dot(mat,a)
np.dot(mat,b)
np.dot(mat,c)
np.dot(mat,d)
np.dot(mat,e)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dot products (shorthand: `@`) can be broadcasted, but you need to make sure the axes align correctly.

```
mat  = np.array([[-0.75,  0   ],
                 [ 0,    -0.75]])

poly = np.array([[ 0,     4],      # a
                 [-4,     8],      # b
                 [-8,     0],      # c
                 [-8,    -4],      # d
                 [-4,    -4]])     # e

out  = (mat @ poly.T).T
```